# Jquery: Mouseover event working in everything but firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, mouseover

I am using the following Jquery to change a bunch of images when their parent is moused over and switch them back after. I am on a mac so I haven't tested firefox for windows but even IE is working here which is a shock to the system. Anyone know why this doesn't work in firefox? It throws up no errors but does nothing.

```
       $('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
             })
   } else {
             $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace("o.png", ".png"));  
             })
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function( event ) {
```